# After running "makemigrations" and "migrate", the tables are not being created within PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to add additional tables to my database for a new app I have integrated in to my Django project.

When I run the `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate`, I can see the models have been created however, the relevant tables aren't being added to my database. The tables for Post, Preference and Comment are being added but the tables for Skill, SwapTags, Tagulous_SwapTags_title and Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies aren't being added. (I can't see any errors to why their not being added)

Here is my migrations file:

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.2 on 2021-05-26 15:22

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone
import tagulous.models.fields
import tagulous.models.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

 operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('content', models.TextField(max_length=1000)),
                ('date_posted', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('image', models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='srv_media')),
                ('likes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('dislikes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Skill',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('count', models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use')),
                ('protected', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0')),
                ('path', models.TextField()),
                ('label', models.CharField(help_text='The name of the tag, without ancestors', max_length=255)),
                ('level', models.IntegerField(default=1, help_text='The level of the tag in the tree')),
                ('parent', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='children', to='sfsrv.skill')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('name',),
                'abstract': False,
                'unique_together': {('slug', 'parent')},
            },
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagTreeModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Tagulous_SwapTags_title',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('count', models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use')),
                ('protected', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('name',),
                'abstract': False,
                'unique_together': {('slug',)},
            },
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('count', models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use')),
                ('protected', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('name',),
                'abstract': False,
                'unique_together': {('slug',)},
            },
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SwapTags',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('hobbies', tagulous.models.fields.TagField(_set_tag_meta=True, blank=True, force_lowercase=True, help_text='This field splits on spaces and commas', initial='eating, coding, gaming', to='sfsrv.Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies')),
                ('skills', tagulous.models.fields.TagField(_set_tag_meta=True, autocomplete_view='swaptags_skills_autocomplete', help_text='This field does not split on spaces', initial='"Accountancy/Tax Returns", "Decorator/Residential Decorator", "Gardener/Home Garden Maintenance", "Gardener/Public Spaces", "Plumber/Home Plumber", Accountancy/Bookkeeping', space_delimiter=False, to='sfsrv.Skill', tree=True)),
                ('title', tagulous.models.fields.SingleTagField(_set_tag_meta=True, blank=True, help_text='This is a SingleTagField - effectively a CharField with dynamic choices', initial='Accountant, Decorator', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='sfsrv.tagulous_swaptags_title')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'swaptags',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('content', models.TextField(max_length=150)),
                ('date_posted', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('post_connected', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='sfsrv.post')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Preference',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('value', models.IntegerField()),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('post', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='sfsrv.post')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'unique_together': {('user', 'post', 'value')},
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
import tagulous.admin
from sfsrv.models import Post, Comment, Preference, SwapTags, Skill

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Preference)

# Register the SwapTags with a custom ModelAdmin
class SwapTagsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")
    list_filter = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")

tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags, SwapTagsAdmin)

# Auto-gen the ModelAdmins for skills and hobbies
tagulous.admin.register(Skill)
tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model)


# Give the Title ModelAdmin the people as inlines
class SwapTagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SwapTags
    extra = 3


class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SwapTagsInline]


tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.title.tag_model, TitleAdmin)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image
import tagulous.models



class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='srv_media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes= models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[:5]

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    @property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post_connected=self).count()

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_connected = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Preference(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value= models.IntegerField()
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ':' + str(self.post) +':' + str(self.value)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ("user", "post", "value")
       
class Skill(tagulous.models.TagTreeModel):
    class TagMeta:
        initial = [
            "Accountancy/Bookkeeping",
            "Accountancy/Tax Returns",
            "Decorator/Residential Decorator",
            "Plumber/Home Plumber",
            "Gardener/Home Garden Maintenance",
            "Gardener/Public Spaces",
        ]
        space_delimiter = False
        autocomplete_view = "swaptags_skills_autocomplete"


class SwapTags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = tagulous.models.SingleTagField(
        initial="Accountant, Decorator",
        help_text=(
            "This is a SingleTagField - effectively a CharField with " "dynamic choices"
        ),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    skills = tagulous.models.TagField(
        Skill, help_text="This field does not split on spaces"
    )
    hobbies = tagulous.models.TagField(
        initial="eating, coding, gaming",
        force_lowercase=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="This field splits on spaces and commas",
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "swaptags"
```

Any suggestions would be welcome! Thank you :-)

Comment: Delete all previous migrations and try again with those commands..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Should I clear the migration history using `python manage.py migrate --fake myapp zero`? and then try to rerun the migration (After deleting the relevant migration files?)

Comment: Yes have u tried?

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried this (Thought I'd try it again for the second time, but the new tables aren't being added)

Comment: Ohh have you registered in your admin.py?

Comment: @Jarjar95 `python manage.py migrate --fake myapp zero` is not ideal for your situation it would only make it more difficult for you. "_the relevant tables aren't being added to my database_" how did you check this? By any chance do you define `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in your settings?

Comment: Are you seeing the model on the admin page and while clicking on it shows error ? if so the problem would be in the migration..

Comment: Hello Nanthakumar, yes that's correct: I can see the models within my Django Admin  Dashboard. But if I try to click on to any of the new models such as SwapTags, I get an error page (ProgrammingError: relation "sfsrv_tagulous_swaptags_title" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "sfsrv_tagulous_swaptags_title"."protected" FROM "sfsrv_tag...)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hello, I logged in to psql, and displayed the list of tables within my database, but the tables which should be there aren't listed :-) All my migrations are showing as up to date.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ - I have updated my original description with the contents of my admin.py file :)

Comment: @Jarjar95 what is `SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model` and `SwapTags.title.tag_model`?? Please show your models...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hey Abdul, I have updated my original question with the contents of my model.py file :-)

Comment: @Jarjar95 I assume you have run used the `--fake` flag while making the migrations incorrectly. I assume you got the error and then used `--fake` then deleted your migrations (generally deleting the migrations can go wrong unless you know what _exactly_ you are doing, or actually are going to delete the database as well) and you are now in this situation yes? I would advice to simply drop the database if there is nothing important. Otherwise you will be left figuring out the correct state of the database and separating / editing the migration files manually as a fix.

Comment: Hello, I've dropped the tables and reran the migration, everything is working perfect now. Thanks for your suggestion!